# Java - How do I undo a hashCode() and read as string?

Tags: java, hash, passwords, hashcode

In my code I want to store passwords... but since it's an online program, I want to keep the passwords secret (duh). So I used `"Password Here".hashCode()`. Perfect. I got a crazy new code. Now how to I see if the password (in the password field (JTextField)) matches the password. I DON'T WANT THE HASHCODE-ED PASSWORD! I WANT THE REAL PASSWORD! (The opposite of hashCode())

```
if (PasswordField.getText().equals("HASH NUMBER HERE!")) {
    login(username, password, address, port);
```

But here I put in the already hashCode()-ed number... And I want it to be able to get the password before I changed it to hashCode()

I want to read the hashCode()-ed password into a not hashCoded()-ed String. the How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: not at all. the number of strings matching a single hashcode is theoretically infinite.

Comment: You can't. You shouldn't be using `hashCode` for this anyway (use a cryptographic hash instead) but hashes are *designed* to be one-way. You check whether or not the passwords match by checking whether their hashes match - that way you don't *need* the original password to be stored...

Comment: Is this a real application or just messing around because you should not use `.hashCode()` to keep password secret or secure...

Comment: I was just messing around!

Comment: Then how should I do this?

Comment: You could use encryption and decryption libraries to encrypt and decrypt the password based on a secret key...

Comment: You don't. If you use a secret key to encrypt a secret key, how do you store your second secret key? With a third key?

Comment: @RealSkeptic what? Maybe re-read his question...

Comment: @brso05 I read it. You do not encrypt passwords. If you encrypt passwords, you'll need to encrypt the key as well.

Comment: @RealSkeptic wrong...you can store the key somewhere where no one has access to.  For what he is trying to do it should work fine. In fact for what he is trying to do he could hard code it on the server...

Comment: A little late but http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords is a good discussion of cryptographic hashing

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "undo" (or "decrypt") a hash code. Hash codes are not a form of encryption.

First of all, you should not use `hashCode()` for passwords. You should use a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) instead.

The whole point of a cryptographic hash function is that it's a **one way** algorithm - given some input, you can compute the hash, but it is (practically) impossible to compute the original input back when you have only the hash.

How this normally works, is like this:

- In a database, you store a user's name and the hash of the user's password.
- When the user logs in, you calculate the hash of the password that the user entered when logging in.
- You compare that hash to the hash in the database. If they are equal, the user entered the correct password.

As you see, it is not necessary to "decrypt" the hash when you do it this way.

In practice, there are a lot more details to it to make it really secure. You should use a strong cryptographic hash function and a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to make it more secure. Make sure you study this carefully before using it in any serious application that's going to be available on the web.

Comment: Good explanation. But at some point, if I need to read the password back. How can i do that with the hashed value

Comment: @MuthaiahPL You cannot, if you have only the hash value. That's the whole point... if you really need the password (by the way, why do you need this? this should not be necessary) you'll need to use some other method instead of hashing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no opposite of hashCode. To check if an entered password is equal to the hashed (stored) version, just hash the entered password and check it against the known (stored) hash. For instance, using the hashCode method, you compare the int values of the passwords:

```
int storedHash = getStoredHash();
String password = passwordField.getText();
if ( storedHash != password.hashCode() ){
    //wrong
}
```

And side note: you might consider using something more secure than hashCode (MD5, SHA, etc...).

Comment: But I don't want people to extract the .jar file and see the passwords in the code!

Comment: They won't, they will see the hashed version of the password (which is what should be stored)

Comment: Wait! But there is a problem. I can't get it from the JTextField. The password the user enters is a string! A hashCode() is a int!

Comment: @Maxie_Z You hash the String from the JTextField. You then compare the hashes.

Comment: String password = PasswordField.getText().hashCode(); I get an error.... `password` needs to be an int!

Comment: Yes, because hashCode returns an int. int passwordHash = passwordField.getText().hashCode();

Comment: A clash - rare but possible depending upon context. This is one of the reasons why other hashing methods are preferred

Comment: I have tried this but its not working... may yo can fix this!  `String password = PasswordField.getText(); 
    password = password.toUpperCase(); 
    int newpassword = password.hashCode();
     if (Integer.toString(newpassword).equals("HASHED PASSWORD")) {
      login(username, password, address, port);`

Comment: Are you sure you want to make the password non-case-sensitive? You should store the hashed password as an `int` and not a string - so you can just compare the `password.hashCode()` with the `int hashedPassword`.

Comment: Not MD5 or SHA. PBKDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt.